# how to use std::atomic<bool> in dispatch block?

Tags: macos, atomic, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c++

There is Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::atomic' error in the following code, also std::mutex is the same case.
I can only use a serial queue to do the sync?

```
__block std::atomic<bool> balance(false); // Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::atomic<bool>' error
dispatch_block_t work = dispatch_block_create(static_cast<dispatch_block_flags_t>(0), ^{
    if (!balance) {
        long l = dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        NSLog(@"task 2 %d", l);
        balance = true;
    }
});
```

Could you please help me out? thanks a lot!

Comment: `^{` doesn't look like c++11.

Comment: it's Grand Central Dispatch in objective-c

Comment: objective-c is not c++11 or compatible with it so I removed that tag.

Comment: This is very confusing. The `std::atomic` doesn't look like Objective-C. If you're dealing with atomic and just setting its value, why add another layer of synchronization if just setting the value? Or, if using synchronization, why bother with atomic? And if you wanted an atomic rather than synchronized property, why not use Objective-C's atomic properties? And what is the purpose of this semaphore?

Answer (score 1):

The `__block` variable ends up getting copied: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1

(I think this operation could in theory use the move constructor, if available? But it doesn't, so here we are.)

Simplest solution is probably to use a `shared_ptr`. Lower-overhead options are possible, but `shared_ptr` has the advantage of being easy to use and giving you appropriate object lifetime management. For example, for the code given here:

```
__block auto balance = std::make_shared<std::atomic<bool>>(false);
dispatch_block_t work = dispatch_block_create(static_cast<dispatch_block_flags_t>(0), ^{
    if (!*balance) {
        long l = dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        NSLog(@"task 2 %d", l);
        *balance = true;
    }
});
```